# Django: Limit the number of selections in the UI using the FilteredSelectMultiple Widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I am using the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget from Django Admin. My form currently looks something like this (I have changes some names for SO but it is functional):

```
class SelectExampleForm(forms.Form):
    class Media:
        css = {'all': ('/static/widgets.css',), }
        js = ('/static/jsi18n.js',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        group_name = kwargs.pop('group_name')
        location = kwargs.pop('location')

        r = super(SelectExampleForm, self).__init__(
            *args, **kwargs)

        # total pool of choices 
        qs = Employee.objects.filter(
            group__name=group_name, town=location
        )

        # Currently selected choices 
        current = Employee.objects.filter(
            group__name=group_name, town=location, attendance__isnull=False
        )

        # populating the widget ... 
        self.fields['personnel'] = \
            forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                queryset=qs,
                widget=FilteredSelectMultiple(
                    'Employee', is_stacked=False),
                label='',
                initial=current,
                show_hidden_initial=True

            )

        return r
```

Although the details of the models aren't important it may help give some context:

- I have a current set of choices.
- There is a pool of potential choices that a user can select from.
- A quota of total selections allowed. This number is less than the number of potential choices.

I would like to limit the number of choices one can select in the UI, so that only a certain number of choices `n` can be selected and appear on the right hand side of the widget.

I am currently validating this on submission of the form, which I will continue to do, but it is somewhat clunky to allow a user to select too many options in the first place.